# Как добавить в виджет select варианты? Python Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, select

Ниже форма, в ней есть поле "Вид образования", есть выбор, но нет вариантов. 
Как настроить варианты (чтобы они появились)?

[image: Нет выбора вариантов]

forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from .models import Anketa

class DateInput(forms.DateInput):
    input_type = 'date'

class Select(forms.Select):
    input_type = 'select'

class AnketaForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Anketa
        fields = [
        'first_name',
        'last_name',
        'middle_name',
        'date_birth',
        'email',
        'telephone',
        'type_education',
        'program',
        'qualification'
        ]
        widgets = {
        'date_birth': DateInput(attrs={'type': 'date'}),
        'type_education': Select()

        }
```

models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class Anketa(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField('Имя', max_length = 30)
    last_name = models.CharField('Фамилия', max_length = 30)
    middle_name = models.CharField('Отчество', max_length = 40)
    date_birth = models.DateField('Дата рождения')
    email = models.EmailField('Электронная почта')
    telephone = models.CharField('Номер контактного телефона', max_length = 30)
    type_education = models.CharField('Вид образования', max_length = 150)
    program = models.CharField('Направление', max_length = 30)
    qualification = models.CharField('Квалификация', max_length = 30)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Анкеты соискателей'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Анкеты соискателей'
```

Логика подсказывает, что изменения нужны в models.py - class Anketa - type_education, в документации не могу найти подходящее под мой пример.

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: А где самое главное-то? `views.py` в студию

Comment: Вопрос в том, чем вы собираетесь его заполнить?

Comment: Хочу сделать выплывающий список из трех значений.
Вот views.py:

~~~
from django.http import Http404, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render

from .forms import AnketaForm
from .models import Anketa
d
def anketa_create_view(request):
 form = AnketaForm(request.POST or None)
 if form.is_valid():
  form.save()

 context = {
        'form': form
 }
 return render(request, "candidate/anketa_create.html", context)
~~~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если планируется использовать изначально предопределенный набор значений для поля `type_education`, то лучшим способом будет задать именнованный аргумент `choices` при определении поля модели:

```
type_education = models.CharField(verbose_name='Вид образования', max_length=5, choices=EDUCATION_TYPES)
```

Где `EDUCATION_TYPES` - это заранее предопределенный кортеж вида:

```
EDUCATION_TYPES = (
     ('sec', 'Среднее'),
     ('high', 'Высшее'),
)
```

Тогда вам не нужно переопределять виджет этого поля в `ModelForm`, поскольку `Select()` с указанными в `EDUCATION_TYPES` значениями будет назначен по умолчанию

Comment: Спасибо! То что надо! :)